# Problem deploying NodeJS API to App Service

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-devops

I am having a weird problem with trying to deploy a nodeJS API to and can't seem to find any realated issues Stack Overflow or Micorsoft. It is a simple teams bot API I am trying to deploy.

Things I've tried:

1. Doing npm run build to make sure it builds. It does.
2. Research where './util' is coming from cannot determine that ts-node does not appear to have this references to this either.

Azure Pipeline:

```yaml
# Node.js Express Web App to Linux on Azure
# Build a Node.js Express app and deploy it to Azure as a Linux web app.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript
    
trigger:
- master

variables:

  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureSubscription: 'xx'

  # Web app name
  webAppName: 'appName-dev'

  # Environment name
  environmentName: 'appName-dev'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '10.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'

    - script: |
        npm install
        npm run build --if-present
      displayName: 'npm install, build and test'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: chatlink-dev'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appType: webAppLinux
              appName: $(webAppName)
              runtimeStack: 'NODE|10.10'
              package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip
              startUpCommand: 'npm i && npm start'
```

Log Message:

```
2021-12-22T04:32:11.764281687Z   _____                               
2021-12-22T04:32:11.764313387Z   /  _  \ __________ _________   ____  
2021-12-22T04:32:11.764318087Z  /  /_\  \___   /  |  \_  __ \_/ __ \ 
2021-12-22T04:32:11.764323187Z /    |    \/    /|  |  /|  | \/\  ___/ 
2021-12-22T04:32:11.764326887Z \____|__  /_____ \____/ |__|    \___  >
2021-12-22T04:32:11.764331087Z         \/      \/                  \/ 
2021-12-22T04:32:11.764334587Z A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X
2021-12-22T04:32:11.764337987Z 
2021-12-22T04:32:11.764341387Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2021-12-22T04:32:11.764344787Z NodeJS quickstart: https://aka.ms/node-qs
2021-12-22T04:32:11.764348087Z NodeJS Version : v10.10.0
2021-12-22T04:32:11.764352387Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
2021-12-22T04:32:11.764355887Z 
2021-12-22T04:32:12.663348363Z Cound not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'
2021-12-22T04:32:12.663483364Z Could not find operation ID in manifest. Generating an operation id...
2021-12-22T04:32:12.663638066Z Build Operation ID: xxx
2021-12-22T04:32:13.389548261Z Environment Variables for Application Insight's IPA Codeless Configuration exists..
2021-12-22T04:32:13.645821166Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2021-12-22T04:32:14.022579568Z Running #!/bin/sh
2021-12-22T04:32:14.023618576Z 
2021-12-22T04:32:14.023642676Z # Enter the source directory to make sure the script runs where the user expects
2021-12-22T04:32:14.023649076Z cd "/home/site/wwwroot"
2021-12-22T04:32:14.031241433Z 
2021-12-22T04:32:14.031263933Z export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH
2021-12-22T04:32:14.031269333Z if [ -z "$PORT" ]; then
2021-12-22T04:32:14.031276233Z      export PORT=8080
2021-12-22T04:32:14.031491834Z fi
2021-12-22T04:32:14.031501034Z 
2021-12-22T04:32:14.031708436Z PATH="$PATH:/home/site/wwwroot" npm i && npm start
2021-12-22T04:32:15.284402609Z npm info it worked if it ends with ok
2021-12-22T04:32:15.285412618Z npm info using npm@6.14.14
2021-12-22T04:32:15.293315385Z npm info using node@v10.10.0
2021-12-22T04:32:18.213321471Z npm info lifecycle teams-bot@1.0.0~preinstall: teams-bot@1.0.0
2021-12-22T04:32:24.493426326Z npm timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 6276ms
2021-12-22T04:32:24.553827307Z npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 59ms
2021-12-22T04:32:26.509050286Z npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 1928ms
2021-12-22T04:32:28.695074538Z npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree Completed in 2206ms
2021-12-22T04:32:29.323668363Z npm timing stage:loadIdealTree Completed in 4822ms
2021-12-22T04:32:29.929012805Z npm timing stage:generateActionsToTake Completed in 434ms
2021-12-22T04:32:30.883252384Z npm timing action:extract Completed in 376ms
2021-12-22T04:32:30.913349983Z npm timing audit submit Completed in 439ms
2021-12-22T04:32:30.924395086Z npm http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits/quick 447ms
2021-12-22T04:32:30.924415087Z npm timing audit body Completed in 9ms
2021-12-22T04:32:30.932385478Z npm timing action:finalize Completed in 42ms
2021-12-22T04:32:30.954075270Z npm timing action:refresh-package-json Completed in 21ms
2021-12-22T04:32:30.955585626Z npm timing action:preinstall Completed in 0ms
2021-12-22T04:32:30.963720723Z npm timing action:build Completed in 8ms
2021-12-22T04:32:30.964885365Z npm timing action:install Completed in 1ms
2021-12-22T04:32:30.973448978Z npm timing action:postinstall Completed in 0ms
2021-12-22T04:32:30.976428487Z npm timing stage:executeActions Completed in 527ms
2021-12-22T04:32:31.000227356Z npm timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 24ms
2021-12-22T04:32:31.004778622Z npm info linkStuff teams-bot@1.0.0
2021-12-22T04:32:31.006571788Z npm info lifecycle teams-bot@1.0.0~install: teams-bot@1.0.0
2021-12-22T04:32:31.016047234Z npm info lifecycle teams-bot@1.0.0~postinstall: teams-bot@1.0.0
2021-12-22T04:32:31.023797317Z npm info lifecycle teams-bot@1.0.0~prepublish: teams-bot@1.0.0
2021-12-22T04:32:31.025007761Z npm info lifecycle teams-bot@1.0.0~prepare: teams-bot@1.0.0
2021-12-22T04:32:31.026173004Z npm timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 12913ms
2021-12-22T04:32:31.992371102Z npm info lifecycle undefined~preshrinkwrap: undefined
2021-12-22T04:32:32.588468683Z npm info lifecycle teams-bot@1.0.0~shrinkwrap: teams-bot@1.0.0
2021-12-22T04:32:32.618280873Z npm info lifecycle teams-bot@1.0.0~postshrinkwrap: teams-bot@1.0.0
2021-12-22T04:32:32.638271803Z npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
2021-12-22T04:32:32.639443546Z npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
2021-12-22T04:32:32.640234375Z 
2021-12-22T04:32:32.647654046Z audited 502 packages in 14.545s
2021-12-22T04:32:33.438689076Z 
2021-12-22T04:32:33.438732677Z 73 packages are looking for funding
2021-12-22T04:32:33.438739877Z   run `npm fund` for details
2021-12-22T04:32:33.438744777Z 
2021-12-22T04:32:33.441068894Z found 0 vulnerabilities
2021-12-22T04:32:33.441087094Z 
2021-12-22T04:32:33.473042036Z npm timing npm Completed in 18311ms
2021-12-22T04:32:33.474150645Z npm info ok 
2021-12-22T04:32:34.485680909Z npm info it worked if it ends with ok
2021-12-22T04:32:34.486949019Z npm info using npm@6.14.14
2021-12-22T04:32:34.488340830Z npm info using node@v10.10.0
2021-12-22T04:32:34.700449238Z npm info lifecycle teams-bot@1.0.0~prestart: teams-bot@1.0.0
2021-12-22T04:32:34.713875839Z npm info lifecycle teams-bot@1.0.0~start: teams-bot@1.0.0
2021-12-22T04:32:34.719416381Z 
2021-12-22T04:32:34.719447882Z > teams-bot@1.0.0 start /home/site/wwwroot
2021-12-22T04:32:34.719453882Z > ts-node ./index.ts
2021-12-22T04:32:34.719457382Z 
2021-12-22T04:32:35.023004283Z internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
2021-12-22T04:32:35.023043883Z     throw err;
2021-12-22T04:32:35.023048883Z     ^
2021-12-22T04:32:35.023052783Z 
2021-12-22T04:32:35.023056383Z Error: Cannot find module './util'
2021-12-22T04:32:35.023065184Z     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
2021-12-22T04:32:35.023069384Z     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
2021-12-22T04:32:35.023073284Z     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
2021-12-22T04:32:35.023076984Z     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
2021-12-22T04:32:35.023080584Z     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/ts-node:9:16)
2021-12-22T04:32:35.023084684Z     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
2021-12-22T04:32:35.023088484Z     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
2021-12-22T04:32:35.023092684Z     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
2021-12-22T04:32:35.023096784Z     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
2021-12-22T04:32:35.023100484Z     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
2021-12-22T04:32:35.043138336Z npm info lifecycle teams-bot@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
2021-12-22T04:32:35.053032011Z npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-12-22T04:32:35.054289721Z npm ERR! errno 1
2021-12-22T04:32:35.064537298Z npm ERR! teams-bot@1.0.0 start: `ts-node ./index.ts`
2021-12-22T04:32:35.065160903Z npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-12-22T04:32:35.073389065Z npm ERR! 
2021-12-22T04:32:35.074245672Z npm ERR! Failed at the teams-bot@1.0.0 start script.
2021-12-22T04:32:35.074926977Z npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-12-22T04:32:35.103775596Z npm timing npm Completed in 747ms
2021-12-22T04:32:35.104568302Z 
2021-12-22T04:32:35.105420809Z npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-12-22T04:32:35.106639918Z npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-12-22T04_32_35_075Z-debug.log
```

What is weird is `./util` is not even used in my project or references. Which leads me to believe

Comment: _"Which leads me to believe..."_ is there meant to be more to this post?

Comment: Can you delete `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file and then run `npm install` again?

Comment: @Bishan Correct, still works locally. I also tried upgrading node version to match what I'm using locally and works as expected.